# 2001 Hyundai Accent handbrake sensor

Tags: hyundai, handbrake, accent

Just wondering if anyone has a video of how to fix the handbrake sensor in a 2001 Hyundai Accent? I can't work out how to get the case off.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this video](https://youtu.be/F51HgjyEUi8?t=2m31s). Basically, there's 2 screws on the sides at the back (you will need to slide your front seats forward and lean them) and a hidden clip at the front.